# Alternative to TCPDF for large-volume pdf generation

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I generate pdf documents with TCPDF. It's fairly easy to setup and very good for creating pdf files with <10 pages.

I can generate 50 pages long PDF files within the 60 seconds default php timeout and can 
generate upto 200 pages when the timeout is set to 300 (SET_TIME_LIMIT(300)).

I have also allocated 256 mb memory in the PHP ini.

Is there an alternative to the likes of TCPDF which generate PDF files faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have shell access via PHP (shell_exec, system or exec) you can split the PDF creation into junks and merge them together with [pdftk](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/10/02/merge-pdf-files/).
With this possibility, you will never reach the timeout limit.
The other possibility is the use XML-FO processor like [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).

Comment: I have never used any of them, so I will have to look into it.